# Explain how to use TextGetTargetedSentiment of AlechmyAPI

Tags: alchemyapi

1) Please explain what is the functionality of TextGetTargetedSentiment.

2) Please provide Java code snippet calling TextGetTargetedSentiment.

**EDIT**

API info is at
http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/textc.html#targetedsentiment

As answered by Zach below, code snippet given by AlchemyAPI is

```
        AlchemyAPI_TargetedSentimentParams sentimentParams = new AlchemyAPI_TargetedSentimentParams();
        sentimentParams.setShowSourceText(true);
        doc = alchemyObj.TextGetTargetedSentiment("This car is terrible.", "car", sentimentParams);
        System.out.print(getStringFromDocument(doc));
```

Result is

```
    :
 <totalTransactions>1</totalTransactions>
<language>english</language>
<text>This car is terrible.</text>
<docSentiment>
    <score>-0.776261</score>
    <type>negative</type>
</docSentiment>
```

If we change a statement to

> "This car is superb."
>   Then result is

```
:
<totalTransactions>1</totalTransactions>
<language>english</language>
<text>This car is superb.</text>
<docSentiment>
    <score>0.695491</score>
    <type>positive</type>
</docSentiment>
```

All files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextGetTargetedSentiment finds the sentiment for a specific keyword within a text. This can be contrasted with document level sentiment (the endpoint TextGetTextSentiment), which looks at the whole text to determine sentiment.

The [AlchemyAPI Java SDK](https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_java) can help you get up and running quickly with the targeted sentiment call.